# Microsoft Access calculated control breaks in Navigation Form

Tags: ms-access

I have a form in Microsoft Access 2013 that uses the following formula in a calculated text box to summarize outcomes:

```
=DCount("[Log]![Outcome]","[Log]","[Log]![Outcome] ='Good' AND [Log]![User]= [Forms]![User Summary]![UserName]")
```

In effect, the formula looks in the "Log" Table and gives me the total count where the "Outcome" is "Good" for the User that matches the current user selected in the "User Summary" form.

The formula works great when I access the "User Summary" form directly. However, if I embed the "User Summary" form into a navigation form, the formula returns an error. The error stops and normal behavior resumes if I open the original "User Summary" form in the background.

Any ideas how to make this work in a Navigation form without having to open the User Summary form in the background? I eventually will be handing the interface to multiple people, and I don't want them to have to open various forms in the background just to get the navigation to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=DCount("[Log]![Outcome]","[Log]","[Log]![Outcome] ='Good' AND [Log]![User]='" & Me.MySubformName!UserName & "'")
```

A bit simplified:

```
=DCount("Outcome","Log","Outcome='Good' AND User='" & Me.MySubformName!UserName & "'")
```

Where `MySubformName` is not the name of the form but the name of the control in the main form that contains the subform.

Depending on where your control is you may need to do something like Forms.MyMainForm.MySubForm!UserName. Basically when your form is embedded in another form you have to call it by starting from the main form and work downwards.

Comment: See also: [Refer to Form and Subform properties and controls](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm) @B.Eskew

Answer (score 0):

The inbuilt Navigation form uses a subform to display your forms.

Unfortunately they also unload the form from the subform container when it isn't selected, so that form isn't actually present in the background. Whilst this is a clever technique to improve perceived performance, it isn't without it's issues if you don't know it's doing it.

This is why most developers make their own Navigation forms.